# why I got Unhandled Exception: type 'List<List<String>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' of 'value' With Flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, addition, collect

I'm trying to get data from a list and then put all the values in a second list.
Unfortunately, I go an error: type 'List<List>' is not a subtype of type 'List' of 'value'
this is the code :

```
  List? getData() {
    setup.generateCsv((event) async {
      List<List<String>> data = [
        ["X", " Y", "Z", "Z"],
        [mevent.data[0], event.data[1], event.data[2]],
      ];
      List data2 = data;
      data2.add(data);
      print("DATA DATA , $data2");
      return data2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add list like

```dart
  List<List<String>> data = [...];
  List<String> data2 = [];
  for (final e in data) {
    data2.addAll(e);
  }
  return data2;
```

Comment: Why not just use [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection)'s [Iterable.flattened](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableIterableExtension/flattened.html)?

Comment: Thanks, this is handy `data2 = data.flattened.toList();`, often forget about collection

Comment: @YeasinSheikh what's the library of flattened ?

Comment: you will get by default, just `import 'package:collection/collection.dart';`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh this didn't show any error. Actually the list  data is changing. for example I have data : [1,2,3,4] and then I have data [2,3,4,5] I want to show these two lists in the same list which is data2 but in different rows. because I have to save the list with headers X ,Y,Z in a csv file

Comment: you like to merge two list ? you can do `newList  =  [...list1, ...list2]`  , also you can use `newList.addAll(secondList)`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh more than two lists because the list data is changing lot of times

Comment: you can do looping and using `.addAll` to add all items on newlist, number doesnt matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251052/discussion-between-asma-and-yeasin-sheikh).